No overload matches this call Overload 1 of 2 (typescript error)
I'm new to Typescript and I'm having this error: No overload matches this call.
Here's the (super long) error message
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(action: (state: { errors: { retailPrice?: string[] | undefined; productName?: string[] | undefined; brandName?: string[] | undefined; COGS?: string[] | undefined; warehouseQuantity?: string[] | undefined; warehouse_enter_date?: string[] | undefined; productDescription?: string[] | undefined; exp_date?: string[] | undefined; }; message: string; } | undefined) => { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | undefined, initialState: { ...; } | undefined, permalink?: string | undefined): [state: ...]', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(prevState: State, formData: FormData) => Promise<{ errors: { retailPrice?: string[] | undefined; productName?: string[] | undefined; brandName?: string[] | undefined; COGS?: string[] | undefined; warehouseQuantity?: string[] | undefined; warehouse_enter_date?: string[] | undefined; productDescription?: string[] | u...' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { errors: { retailPrice?: string[] | undefined; productName?: string[] | undefined; brandName?: string[] | undefined; COGS?: string[] | undefined; warehouseQuantity?: string[] | undefined; warehouse_enter_date?: string[] | undefined; productDescription?: string[] | undefined; exp_date?: string[] | undefined;...'.

Argument of type '(prevState: State, formData: FormData) => Promise<{ errors: { retailPrice?: string[] | undefined; productName?: string[] | undefined; brandName?: string[] | undefined; COGS?: string[] | undefined; warehouseQuantity?: string[] | undefined; warehouse_enter_date?: string[] | undefined; productDescription?: string[] | u...' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { errors: { retailPrice?: string[] | undefined; productName?: string[] | undefined; brandName?: string[] | undefined; COGS?: string[] | undefined; warehouseQuantity?: string[] | undefined; warehouse_enter_date?: string[] | undefined; productDescription?: string[] | undefined; exp_date?: string[] | undefined;...'.
      Types of parameters 'prevState' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type '{ errors: { retailPrice?: string[] | undefined; productName?: string[] | undefined; brandName?: string[] | undefined; COGS?: string[] | undefined; warehouseQuantity?: string[] | undefined; warehouse_enter_date?: string[] | undefined; productDescription?: string[] | undefined; exp_date?: string[] | undefined; }; mess...' is not assignable to type 'State'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'State'.ts(2769)

I have two files. One is actions.ts where I define State and the function createProduct.
const FormSchema = z.object({
  _id: z.string(),
  productName: z.string({
    required_error: "Product name is required",
  }),
  brandName: z.string(),
  retailPrice: z.coerce
    .number()
    .gt(0, { message: "Please enter amount greater than 0" }),
  COGS: z.coerce
    .number()
    .gt(0, { message: "Please enter amount greater than 0" }),
  warehouseQuantity: z.coerce.number(),
  warehouse_enter_date: z.string(),
  productDescription: z.string(),
  exp_date: z.string(),
});

const CreateProduct = FormSchema.omit({ _id: true });
const UpdateProduct = FormSchema.omit({ _id: true });

export type State = {
  errors?: {
    productName?: string[];
    brandName?: string[];
    productDescription?: string[];
    warehouseQuantity?: string[];
    retailPrice?: string[];
    COGS?: string[];
    warehouseEnterDate?: string[];
    expiryDate?: string[];
  };
  message?: string | null;
};

export async function createProduct(prevState: State, formData: FormData) {
  const validatedFields = CreateProduct.safeParse({
    productName: formData.get("productName"),
    brandName: formData.get("brandName"),
    productDescription: formData.get("productDescription"),
    warehouseQuantity: formData.get("warehouseQuantity"),
    retailPrice: formData.get("retailPrice"),
    COGS: formData.get("COGS"),
    warehouseEnterDate: formData.get("warehouseEnterDate"),
    expiryDate: formData.get("expiryDate"),
  });

  if (!validatedFields.success) {
    return {
      errors: validatedFields.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
      message: "Missing Fields. Failed to Create Product.",
    };
  }

  validatedFields.data.retailPrice *= 100;
  validatedFields.data.COGS *= 100;
  const productData = validatedFields.data;

  // try {...
   // this is just a try/catch block to call API and create product
}

and another file is create-product.tsx. This file contains the UI for the form and from here I call createProduct function with useFormState.
export default function Form() {
  const initialState = { message: null, errors: {} };
const [state, dispatch] = useFormState(createProduct, initialState);

  return (
    <form action={dispatch} className="space-y-5">
      <div className=" bg-white px-10 py-10 rounded-lg shadow-md space-y-4">
        <div className="space-y-2">
          <label
            htmlFor="productName"
            className="block text-zinc-700 font-semibold text-normal"
          >
            Product name
          </label>
          <TextField.Root
          aria-describedby="customer-error"
            id="productName"
            name="productName"
            placeholder="Product name"
          ></TextField.Root>
        </div>
        <div id="customer-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
        {state.errors?.productName &&
          state.errors.productName.map((error: string) => (
            <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-500" key={error}>
              {error}
            </p>
          ))}
      </div>

        <div className="space-y-2">
          <label
            htmlFor="brandName"
            className="block text-zinc-700 font-semibold text-normal"
          >
            Brand name
          </label>
          <TextField.Root
            id="brandName"
            name="brandName"
            placeholder="Brand name"
          ></TextField.Root>
        </div>

        // ... other fields in the form
      <div className="mt-6 flex justify-end gap-4">
        <Link
          href="/dashboard/product"
          className="flex h-10 items-center rounded-lg bg-gray-100 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors hover:bg-gray-200"
        >
          Cancel
        </Link>
        <Button type="submit">Create Product</Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

I'm following the Next js tutorial to build a simple Nextjs app. When I follow their code there's no problem but when I apply to my own code, I got this error. I have checked if I wrote exactly like them but still got error. Here's the code for your reference https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/blob/main/dashboard/final-example/app/lib/actions.ts Look at actions.ts in final-example/libs and create-form in final-example/ui/invoices.
